# JQuery Validate Regex Rule Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a regular expression rule setup for jQuery Validate.   However, once the highlight method is fired, I can't seem to get the Unhighlight method to fire, no matter what I type in the field.

Here is a sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://eat-sleep-code.com/style/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://eat-sleep-code.com/style/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://eat-sleep-code.com/style/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eat-sleep-code.com/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eat-sleep-code.com/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" defer="defer"></script>       
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Example Form    
            </legend>
            <ol>
                <li id="ExampleInputRow">
                    <input type="text" id="ExampleInput" name="ExampleInput" class="form-control" maxlength="256" />
                </li>
            </ol>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharactersRegex = '/^[a-z0-9]{8,32}$/ig';

        $.validator.addMethod('lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharacters', function (value, element, parameter) {
            return value.match(lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharactersRegex);
        }, '');

        $.validator.setDefaults({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                $(error).insertBefore($(element));
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
            },
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('input:text').blur();
                    $('input:password').blur();
                    $('textarea').blur();
                }, 10);
            },
            onkeyup: function (element) {
                  $('#ExampleInput').valid();
            }
        });


        var validator = $("form").validate({
            rules: {
                ExampleInput: {lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharacters: true}    
            },
            messages: {
                ExampleInput: {lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharacters: "You must enter between 8 and 32 numbers and letters."}
            }
        });

        function Validate() {
            return $('form').valid();
        }

    });
</script>
```

If I type 8 letters the regular expression should be matched and the error message should be cleared.   But this isn't happening.   I put a breakpoint in Google Chrome developer tools on the contents of the unhighlight method but it never seems to be hit.

Comment: Also note that your `onkeyup` callback function should not have a `.valid()` inside of it, and what is `$('#ExampleInput')` supposed to be?  You should have `this.element(element)` to trigger validation within this callback instead of `.valid()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not passing a regex to the match, you are passing a string

```
var lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharactersRegex = /^[a-z0-9]{8,32}$/ig;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9653awnn/)

---

Also there is no need to write a new method to use a regex validation, jQuery validator's additional-method.js has a rule called pattern which can be used for this purpose

```
 var lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharactersRegex = /^[a-z0-9]{8,32}$/ig;
 var validator = $("form").validate({
     rules: {
         ExampleInput: {
             pattern: lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharactersRegex
         }
     },
     messages: {
         ExampleInput: {
             lettersNumbersOnlyMinMaxCharacters: "You must enter between 8 and 32 numbers and letters."
         }
     }
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9653awnn/1/)